# Repeat a pandas DataFrame by datetime rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a pandas DataFrame and a datetime column by month. I am wondering how to assign the DataFrame to each date so each date will have the same repeated DataFrame.

DataFrame:

```
data = {'product_name': ['laptop', 'printer', 'tablet', 'desk', 'chair'],
        'price': [1200, 150, 300, 450, 200]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['a123','a518','a608','a790','a890'])

     product_name  price
a123       laptop   1200
a518      printer    150
a608       tablet    300
a790         desk    450
a890        chair    200
```

and dates:

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='2020-07', end='2025-07', freq='M'))

            0
0  2020-07-31
1  2020-08-31
2  2020-09-30
3  2020-10-31
4  2020-11-30
..        ...
56 2025-03-31
57 2025-04-30
58 2025-05-31
59 2025-06-30
60 2025-07-31
```

Comment: [cross merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) them for a cartesian product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `repeat` the index + `reindex` with it + multiplicate and `assign` the dates to a new column + sort (optional):

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='2020-07', end='2025-07', freq='M')
df = (df.reindex(df.index.repeat(len(dates)))
      .assign(date=dates.tolist()*len(df))
      .rename_axis('').sort_values(by=['date','']).rename_axis(None))
```

Output:

```
     product_name  price       date
a123       laptop   1200 2020-07-31
a518      printer    150 2020-07-31
a608       tablet    300 2020-07-31
a790         desk    450 2020-07-31
a890        chair    200 2020-07-31
...           ...    ...        ...
a123       laptop   1200 2025-06-30
a518      printer    150 2025-06-30
a608       tablet    300 2025-06-30
a790         desk    450 2025-06-30
a890        chair    200 2025-06-30

[300 rows x 3 columns]
```